# como concatenar índice de array com seu anterior?

Tags: php

Estou tentando, dentro de uma `classe`, criar uma propriedade que será populada por um array.

O problema é que o segundo índice desse array depende do valor do primeiro e gostaria de concatenar.

```
private $site = array (
    "dominio"           => "site.com.br",
    "www"               => "www.".->dominio,
```

Como fazer isso?

Comment: Como o `$site` está sendo populado? Através de um set?

Comment: não! Através do próprio array. Editei a pergunta.

Comment: Que tal `$site = ["dominio" => "site.com.br"]; $site["www"] = "www." . $site["dominio"];`? Você também pode usar a função `end($site)` para retornar o último elemento do array, apenas tome cuidado que o ponteiro interno será modificado.

Comment: "www"               => $site["dominio"],, não rolou;

Comment: até porque a variável (array) $site ainda não está completa nessa linha!

Comment: Algo assim, https://ideone.com/TaNLrQ?

Answer (score 1):

Não tem como. O que você pode fazer é definir as propriedades diretamente:

```
<?php

class Site 
{
    private $site = [
        'domain' => 'site.com.br',
        'www' => 'www.site.com.br'
    ];
}
```

Comment: era isso que eu não gostaria de fazer. kkk. queria fazer automático!

Comment: do jeito que você quer não dá. O que você pode fazer é criar isso no construtor, mas não vejo um benefício aparente.

Comment: eu também não vejo!